# Jquery Terminal register & login

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I have question, i want user register then login but here it's error anyone can help me ? i saw the documentation . here is link of the documentation [jquery termi[jquery terminal][1](https://terminal.jcubic.pl)nal](https://terminal.jcubic.p)

here is my script:

```
if (command == 'register') {

        term.push(function(command, term) {
            term.pause();

            $.ajax({
                    url: "register.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {data_register : command },
                    success: function (msg) {
                       term.echo(yellow('Data Saved Successfully !'));

                       term.resume();
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       term.resume();
                    }

                });

        }, 
        {

          prompt: " > "
        });

    } else if (command == 'login'){
      login: function(user, password, callback) {
        if (user == 'demo' && password == 'secret') {
            callback('SECRET TOKEN');
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
      }
    }
```

this line's error :

```
else if (command == 'login'){
          login: function(user, password, callback) {
            if (user == 'demo' && password == 'secret') {
                callback('SECRET TOKEN');
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
          }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: One more comment if you're using push in register it will wait for next command user until it will execute register, you need to put that ajax call without push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid JavaScript you have label and function declaration, which should be put in an object like this:

```
var x = {
   login: function() {
   }
};
```

which should be part of object in second argument which is options object.

```
.terminal(function(command) {

   if (command === 'register') {
   }
}, {
   login: function(...) {
      ...
   }
});
```

and for your exact problem on having login command, that login you in, you need to invoke login method like this:

```
} else if (command == 'login'){
   term.login(function(user, password, callback) {
      // to get the token you should send user and password to the server
      if (user == 'demo' && password == 'secret') {
        callback('SECRET TOKEN');
      } else {
        callback(null);
      }
   });
} else if (term.token()) {
   // here are commands that will only work after user login
   // but you need to know that user may add token in developer tools
   // so you should use additional check if token is valid by sending token
   // to the server, or if you're invoking command on the server then just
   // send the token and validate it there
} else {
   term.error('invalid command');
}
```

Comment: hahaha commented by the author, thank you dude. it works and can i contact you by email ?

Comment: @RobyFirnando sure my email is jcubic@onet.pl.